# Do I need to rank my variables before computing kendall's tau-b?

Tags: r, statistics, correlation, statistical-test

I want to do a Kendall's tau-b rank correlation test on two variables to see if they are correlated. Both variables are continuous, strongly right skewed and  have many ties. That is why i've chosen to do this non-parametric test. Neither variable is ranked. To do the do a Kendall's tau-b rank correlation test i'm using the following command in R

```
cor.test(x=db$independat.variable, y=db$dependat.variable, method = 'kendall').
```

It may seem like a stupid question but I don't know whether I'm supposed to rank my data for each variable before i run this command or if it computes the ranks itself.
Also i read that for Kendall's tau-b the data need to be a square. How do I tell if my data is square?

Comment: This question is better suited for https://stats.stackexchange.com. This should help you https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/300882/p-values-for-kendalls-tau-b-in-kendall-r-package. I've run Spearman rank tests in R before, which you don't have to pre-rank. As long as your relationship is monotonic, you can use the Kendall's rank without doing anything to your data (i.e. ranking, transforming etc.). Also, here's a link to an example of a square table https://wiki.q-researchsoftware.com/wiki/Correspondence_Analysis_of_Square_Tables. Basically, you have the same columns as rows.

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry for posting on the wrong site.

Comment: No worries, Just gotta be more thorough with your searches in the future!